# Javascript Date issue, incorrect timezone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, parseint

I got this strange JavaScript bug that I can seem to work arround or fix.

I am using some code to make 2 JavaScript dates, to insert events into a calendar component.
The dates are built the following way:

```
var endDate = new Date();
var startDate = new Date();

startDate.setDate(startDateDay);
startDate.setMonth(startDateMonth);
startDate.setFullYear(startDateYear);
startDate.setHours(2, 0, 0, 0);

endDate.setDate(endDateDay);
endDate.setMonth(endDateMonth);
endDate.setFullYear(endDateYear);
endDate.setHours(2, 0, 0, 0);
```

So, the dates are built using integers. These integers are determined by input, and using the debugger I can see 100% positive they are coming in correctly.
Now, ill describe 3 walkthroughs, 2 where it goes correctly and 1 where it goes wrong.

---

Using the following input:

```
endDateDay = 20
endDateMonth = 9
endDateYear = 2014
```

Gives the following date object as result:

```
Tue Oct 20 2014 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)
```

---

Using this input:

```
endDateDay = 13
endDateMonth = 9
endDateYear = 2014
```

Gives the following date object as result:

```
Tue Oct 13 2014 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)
```

---

Now, using this input:

```
endDateDay = 27
endDateMonth = 9
endDateYear = 2014
```

Gives the following date object as result:

```
Mon Oct 27 2014 02:00:00 **GMT+0100** (W. Europe Standard Time)
```

As you can see, for some strange reason the TimeZone is off. This gives errors in my application, and I need to find a way to get it fixed. Though, I cannot find any solution to it, let alone understand why it is actually happening.

PS: I am using Google Chrome

Comment: In what way is it off? The clocks in Western Europe go back to standard time on October 26th... what did you expect, and why?

Comment: Look at the tiemzones, one is **Daylight** time, the other is **Standard** time (though the timezone names may be different to what you're used to).

Answer (score 2):

The answer was indeed the difference in the daylight savings time, which I completly oversaw. Thanks to finding this out I also found a solution to my problem.

I used this link to further assist me, might it help someone in the future:
http://javascript.about.com/library/bldst.htm

Cheers!