# Date Range Picker (JavaScript Component for Bootstrap) picks the wrong date on specific day

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker

Currently I have been working with code which I am not the author and the user spotted a very specific problem I couldn’t find an answer to at all.

The page in question uses the [Date Range Picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com) component to pick two dates (start and end).

Whenever someone clicks specifically on the day `16/10/2016` it is automatically shifted to `17/10/2016`.

This was tested in multiple computers and browsers to no effect, I couldn’t trace down the issue with the debugger either.

Any other day, of any month, on any year, returns no problem at all. It only happens on the day `16/10/2016`, and only if that date is the End date, it can be the Start date with no issues.

The current version: 2.1.24

Here is the code used:

```
<section class="col-md-4"> <!-- Selecionar Datas-->
    <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-right">
        <input type="hidden" id="dt_inicio_afastamento">
        <input type="hidden" id="dt_fim_afastamento">
        <label class="control-label">Escolha o intervalo de datas</label>
        <i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        <input id="escolhe_data" name="escolhe_data" class="input-mini form-control" type="text">
    </div>
</section>
```

And the Script:

```
    $('input[name="escolhe_data"]').daterangepicker({
        showDropdowns: true,
        autoApply: true,
        autoUpdateInput: true,
        locale: {
            "format": "DD/MM/YYYY",
            "separator": " - ",
            "applyLabel": "Aplicar",
            "cancelLabel": "Cancelar",
            "fromLabel": "De",
            "toLabel": "Até",
            "customRangeLabel": "Outro",
            "weekLabel": "S",
            "daysOfWeek": ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sab"],
            "monthNames": ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro" ],
            "firstDay": 1
        },
        alwaysShowCalendars: true
    },
    function(start, end, label) {
      //console.log($('#escolhe_data').data());

    });

    $('#escolhe_data').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        $('#dt_inicio_afastamento').val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        $('#dt_fim_afastamento').val(picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    });
```

Comment: Your last input should not have a closing input statement. Thats one thing.

Comment: True, thanks for noticing, norcal, that doesn't change the behavior of the code though.

Comment: No it does not but it stood out to me. Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256145/javascript-date-issue-incorrect-timezone, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488313/javascripts-getdate-returns-wrong-date,

Comment: I don't really know how to, the component has over 1500 lines and the code will not work without it.

Comment: Through @chiliNUT comment i could find out it is related to the end days of daylight saving time, though i still don't know how to fix it. It is a great step forward, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the links posted by chiliNUT I was able to pinpoint the problem.
It was related to the end of daylight savings.
Having the user select the hour as well fixed the issue.
This can be done using the option `"timePicker": true`
in the `$().daterangepicker({ })` configuration.

Thanks chiliNUT and everyone that helped!

Comment: glad my links helped! Dates in javascript are an ever-present source of annoyance at work for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Going to add to this..in case it helps but i did +1 the OP answer.

Here is some other features you can add as well. That does not use autoupdate and time zone will not affect it even if wrongly set.

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="escolhe_data"]').daterangepicker({
        timePicker: true,
        timePickerIncrement: 30,
        locale: {
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'
        },
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    });

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($('input[name="daterange"]').length) {
            $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker("close");
      }
    });
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/kensoubf/